# How to Export to RTF Without Messing Up Table Formatting?

Tags: linux, script, libreoffice-writer, rtf

I have to write several similar reports on LibreOffice Writer. The reports all follow the same template with very minor changes between them: I only change the date and a few simple fields. So, naturally, I'm looking for a way to automate this. I thought I'd save my template as RTF and have a script generate the filled-in reports by changing appropriate parts in the RTF. This works OK except that table formatting goes out the window: the cells become much tighter (no space between cell borders and cell contents) and some borders of the table go missing.
Has anyone faced this before? Any idea on how to fix it?
Is there maybe a better way to automate the filling of odt templates?

---

**EDIT** I'm Perl- and Bash-literate so feel free to suggest a CPAN module or some such trick...

Comment: Have you thought about using HTML? Can you post a sample sheet so we can see what might be the issue?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have many things on my plate at the moment and this just keeps sliding down my priority list. I will post screenshots as soon as I have time.